# Using https as standard with django project

Tags: python, django, shopify

I am learning django and trying to complete my first webapp.

I am using shopify api & boilder plate ([starter cod](https://github.com/aorzh/shopify_django_app)e) and am having an issue with the final step of auth.

Specifically, the redirect URL -- it's using HTTP:// when it should NOT and I don't know how to change it..

```
#in my view

def authenticate(request):

    shop = request.GET.get('shop')

    print('shop:', shop)
    if shop:
        scope = settings.SHOPIFY_API_SCOPE
        redirect_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('shopify_app_finalize')) #try this with new store url?
        print('redirect url', redirect_uri) # this equals http://myherokuapp.com/login/finalize/
        permission_url = shopify.Session(shop.strip()).create_permission_url(scope, redirect_uri)
        return redirect(permission_url)

    return redirect(_return_address(request))
```

Which is a problem because my app uses the Embedded Shopify SDK which causes this error to occur at the point of this request
`Refused to frame 'http://my.herokuapp.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "child-src 'self' https://* shopify-pos://*". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'child-src' is used as a fallback.`

How do i change the URL to use HTTPS?

Thank you so much in advance. Please let me know if I can share any other details but my code is practically identical to that [starter code](https://github.com/aorzh/shopify_django_app)

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Django doc says about `build_absolute_uri`:

> Mixing HTTP and HTTPS on the same site is discouraged, therefore
>   build_absolute_uri() will always generate an absolute URI with the
>   same scheme the current request has. If you need to redirect users to
>   HTTPS, it’s best to let your Web server redirect all HTTP traffic to
>   HTTPS.

So you can do two things:

1. Make sure your site runs entirely on HTTPS (preferred option): Setup your web server to use HTTPS, see the Heroku documentation on how to do this. Django will automatically use HTTPS for `request.build_absolute_uri` if the incoming request is on HTTPS.
   I'm not sure what gets passed in the `shop` parameter but if it contains personal data I'd suggest to use HTTPS anyway.
2. Create the URL yourself:

   ```
   url = "https://{host}{path}".format(
       host = request.get_host(),
       path = reverse('shopify_app_finalize'))
   ```

   But you will still need to configure your server to accept incoming HTTPS requests.